# How to get measument name out of a string in PHP

Tags: php, string

I have a feed in array form which contains area of construction

```
$x['AC']="25";
```

sometime it comes with the measurement value attached in the string itself

```
     $x['AC']="25mt2"; or $x['AC']="25 mt2"; or $x['AC']="25m2";
     $x['AC']="25ht2"; or $x['AC']="25 ht2"; or $x['AC']="25h2";
```

how can I detect this and then clean the value of the array to just number .
and once its detected I have to create a string like

```
mt2[;;;]25 or ht2[;;;]25
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a preg to remove other caracters than numbers:

```
   $x['AC'] = preg_replace('/\D+/','',$x['AC']);
```

But would leave any additional value besides the 25 that you refer, but if 25 is the first number, i would use a preg to get the first numbers in the string:

```
 if(!is_numeric($x['AC'])){
       preg_match('/^\d+/',$x['AC'],$nr);
       $x['AC'] = $nr[0];
  }
```

To get the inside mt or ht also, i would modify the regex like:

```
  if(!is_numeric($x['AC'])){
       preg_match('/^(\d+)\s?(.*)$/',$x['AC'],$nr);
       $x['AC'] = $nr[1];
       $mtORht = $nr[2];
  }
```

OK, resuming, so m2 is default, and for anything else you wish to create a variable with that value in array:
OK, float values too:

```
 if(!is_numeric($x['AC'])){

       preg_match('/^([0-9\.]+)\s?(.*)$/',$x['AC'],$nr);  //$x['AC']="25 ht2" 
      $theValue = $nr[1]; //25
      $theMeasurementName = $nr[2];  //ht2
      //creating the variable:
      if(!stristr($theMeasurementName, 'm')){ // if no "m" is found, the m you wish to omit.
          ${$theMeasurementName} = $theValue; // $ht2[] = 25 
      } 
  }
```

Comment: @lonut thats okay but I have to detect the type of measurement and use it to form a string like `m2[;;;]25 or ht2[;;;]25 `

Comment: @Vikram, i'm unclear of what you are trying to accomplish, you wish to get the "mt" or ht" or any character that's between the numbers ?

Comment: @lonut Actually I have create string depending on the measurment provided in the array like if there is no measure ment then by default I have to use m2 , or else i have to use the measurment which is provided int he array

Comment: @lonut and for float values what should I change in your script

Comment: I tested it here http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/bb7aa45ea4e2cbd2b7acce3ff5738cde29c4b25c but it shows wrong result

Comment: with the changed regex; http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/8204be08ff03d9fd8b002976dfcdd43191a4668a

Answer (score 2):

You can just cast it to an integer and if there is a non numerical value it will get cut off, like this:

```
$x['AC'] = (int) $x['AC'];
```

example input/output:

```
25      -> 25
25mt2   -> 25
25ht2   -> 25
25 mt2  -> 25
25 ht2  -> 25
25m2    -> 25
25h2    -> 25
```

**EDIT:**

As per your updated question you can use [`preg_match()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) to create your string:

```
preg_match("/^(\d+)\s*(.*?)$/", $x["AC"], $m);
echo (empty($m[2])?"m2":$m[2]) . "[;;;;]" . $m[1];
```

Comment: I updated my question please have a look , ALl I am trying to do is to create a string with the measurement provided in the array . Like is in array its 25m2 then I have to create m2[;;;]24

Comment: @Vikram But then thing with the default value http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29970029/how-to-get-measument-name-out-of-a-string-in-php#comment48060317_29970073 isn't in your question! You might want to add it into your question and not under someones answer!

Answer (score 0):

```
$match = array();
preg_match('/^\d+/', $string, $match));
echo $match[0];
```

Regex:

- `^`    -> begin with
- `\d+`  -> any digit repeated